# Deck suggestions for easier cleaning/Leaf removal

Tags: deck, cleaning, gardening

I'm building a new deck to replace my current one, and I wanted to avoid a huge annoyance I have with my current deck. My current deck is split level (assume in the image below, the right half is 6-8" lower than the left side), and all leaves/sweetgum balls/pollen/acorns tend to collect on the lower half. I would love to have an open section on the deck that I can sweep everything to, and simply push off my deck into the area to the left (either into a garbage can below, or simply just onto the lawn).

I was considering paying some additional money to add a gate there, so I can open it when I want to sweep (or move furniture to the area below, or what have you), but thought I would farm out some other suggestions. Any other ideas that might be cheaper and/or more convenient?

[image: Deck layout]

Comment: Your _current_ deck has a step in it. Will the new one? If the new one doesn't, it may not collect leaves like the old one does and you may be looking to solve a problem that won't exist.

Comment: @FreeMan The new one will not. That's what I'm hoping, but I'd rather be safe than sorry. I don't want to be kicking myself this fall after spending all this money on a brand new deck.

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends what your local applicable "deck railing" regulations/requirements are. I've seen plenty with horizontal railings (or "benches along the railings" even) that it's no problem to sweep stuff under right off the edge. I guess on one I'm thinking of the local rules seem to allow the fixed benches to be open underneath but areas without benches appear to have the 4" ball test requirement.

Those requirements may vary with height above ground.

Comment: I would think that almost any kind of railing system with the bottom rail 3-1/2 inches (the width of a 2x4) above the deck would allow for leaves and other debris to be blown off.  The railings where the spindles go all the way down and attach to the band board (?) might create more of a barrier.

Comment: @SteveSh This is a good point. My current railing has only ~1" of space between the deck board and the bottom railing. I suppose a (normal?) railing with 3.5" of space underneath should be sufficient clearance for the sweetgum balls and any leaves. Is 3.5" the standard, or should I make a special request?

Comment: If your local regs are of the 4" test ball favor (and they might NOT be - so check), 3-7/8's would suit. 3-1/2 lets your lazy carpenter lay a 2x4 on the deck to hold the bottom rail, but is not any particular standard AFAIK.

Comment: +1 with Ecnerwal.  When I did my and my son's decks (I'm not a pro), I just used a 2x4 on edge as the spacer for the lower rail.  Yeah, I was lazy!  But it was easy.

Comment: @SteveSh  Lazy people work smarter to make life easy.  You think conveyor belts were invented by someone who liked carrying 100 pound bags around.